# How to return JSON result by using LINQ in WCF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, wcf

I am new to WCF. I am trying to create List with LINQ result by using Entity Framework. I want to return JSON data. But i am not able to get it. I am getting error like Notsupportedexception was unhandled by user code. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my Service Constructor:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
UriTemplate = "getcontact")]
List<string> JSONDataAll();
```

If i return like this its working fine:

```
public List<String> JSONDataAll()
{   
var users = (from u in db.Tbl_Users select u).ToList();
var finalList= users.Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
return st;
}
```

In this case its showing error:

```
public List<String> JSONDataAll()
{
var users = (from u in db.Tbl_Users
select new
{ u.UserName,
u.UserAddress
}).ToList();
return users;
}
```

Comment: I tried that one also. Its showing error like Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FslService.Tbl_Users>

Comment: I didn't suggest to return anonymous type, since you return list of `Tbl_Users`, you can just do `var result = (from u in db.Tbl_Users select u);`, then you're golden

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra. Yeah i am getting it without any condition. But if i try to give some conditions in LINQ query its showing conversion error :(

Comment: it's a different question then, your code doesn't show any filter condition, please update your code that uses `select u` with conditions

Comment: @ Yuliam Chandra. I have updated my code above. Please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using WCF, to do a projection (select clause) you can create a new type as return type instead of anonymous object or a derived object and the EF entity can't be used to do a projection.

The derived object might cause the `localhost.com` issue per the discussion, probably there is an invalid proeprty value. And you can also take the [benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836803) of configuring it with `DataMember` attribute.

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDataResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And change the return type of the WCF operation.

```
public List<UserDataResponse> JSONDataAll()
{
    var users = (from u in db.Tbl_Users
                select new UserDataResponse
                {
                    UserName = u.UserName,
                    UserAddress = u.UserAddress
                });
    return users.ToList();
}
```