# WCF Rest ERR_CONNECTION_RESET not large response

Tags: wcf, iis

The error code is absolutely terrible, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET has a host of causes and the causes that I found on other questions were related to having too small of a MaxRequestLength for large web service calls.  The data I was returning was only a couple of kB though, so this couldn't be the issue.

Here is my interface code

```
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  UriTemplate = "GetReportByID?ReportID={ReportID}")]
[OperationContract]
UsageReport GetReportByID(int ReportID);
```

This was the implementation

```
public UsageReport GetReportByID(int ReportID)
{
    return new UsageReport(ReportID);
}
```

And this was the class code for UsageReport

```
[DataContract]
public class UsageReport
{
 [DataMember]
List<UsageItem> RL;

  public UsageReport(int reportID)
{
       RL = new List<UsageItem>();

        using (SqlDataReader dr = DBUtility.ExecuteReader(cmd, "DBString"))
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                ItemNumber = dr["ItemID"] as int? ?? 0;
                RL.Add(new UsageItem(ItemNumber));
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
}



public class UsageItem
{
    int ItemNumber;

    public UsageItem(int ItemNumber)
    {
        this.ItemNumber = ItemNumber;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was my UsageItem class,  I was missing the necessary DataContract and DataMember fields.

```
[DataContract]
public class UsageItem
{
[DataMember]
int ItemNumber;

public UsageItem(int ItemNumber)
  {
    this.ItemNumber = ItemNumber;


  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use WCF services without specifying `DataContract` and `DataMember`, because lot of classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836683/when-to-use-datacontract-and-datamember-attributes  this answer claims that you can, but apparently you lose a lot of benefits when you do so.

Comment: please check this my question , i want to use `JSON.Net` and `WCF` toghether. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754874/how-to-use-wcf-services-without-datacontract-and-datamember

Comment: Thank you so much, DaneEdw.  I wasted 4 hours trying to find out why my connection was being reset.  Your answer saved me.

Comment: If applying a DataMember to properties, it must contain a `set` for it to serialise (ie, it cannot be readonly). Tip: The set can be blank ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add a solution related to a case where WCF is used on the server side:

1. Add `diagnostics` to `web.config` (taken from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/12/30/collecting-diagnostics-for-wcf-hosted-in-iis-web-service-performance-related-issues/)):

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <configuration>
        <system.diagnostics>
          <sources>
             <source name="System.Net" switchValue="Verbose">
                 <listeners>
                     <add name="SystemNetTrace"/>
                 </listeners>
             </source>
             <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                 <listeners>
                     <add name="wcftrace" />
                 </listeners>
             </source>
             <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">       
                 <listeners>
                     <add name="wcfmessages" />
                 </listeners>
             </source>
             <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose">
                 <listeners>
                     <add name="wcfmessages" />
                 </listeners>
             </source>
          </sources>
          <sharedListeners> 
              <add name="SystemNetTrace" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, Callstack" initializeData="C:\Traces\System_Net.txt" />
              <add name="wcftrace" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, Callstack" initializeData="C:\Traces\WCFTrace.svclog" />
              <add name="wcfmessages" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, Callstack" initializeData="C:\Traces\WCFMessages.svclog" />
          </sharedListeners>
          <trace autoflush="true" />
        </system.diagnostics>
      </configuration>
   ```
2. Reproduce the error, then go to the trace folder (`C:\Traces`, in this example). There will be 2 `svclog` files there: `WCFMessages.svclog` and `WCFTrace.svclog`.
3. Open the file named `WCFMessages.svclog`. A "Microsoft Service Trace Viewer" window will open, showing errors with a red color.
   If no errors are displayed, open `WCFTrace.svclog`, and the errors (in red) would be there.

- In my case, it was a `System.Runtime.Serialization` error because of a lack of `DataContract` attribute.