# what is the point of using [Datamember] in c#?

Tags: c#, datamember

I've been looking this up but I just can't seem to understand the point or the advantages of using it when should I use it?

Comment: Did you see this question? [When to use DataContract and DataMember attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836683)

Comment: Its functionality is described in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=net-5.0 so what precisely are you not understanding? If you see no point in using it - why did you post this question? did you  see it somewhere? do you have a sample?

Comment: @greenjaed thanks! that cleared up a little bit of my confusion

Comment: @sommmen I am working on an ASP.NET and I saw almost all the variables that where pulling from the database we're using this and I didn't know if I would do it for my variable as well.